# How to do a binary install of Python 2.7 on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11?

Tags: software-installation, python, upgrade, suse

My SLES11 box came with Python 2.6 installed. I would like to upgrade to 2.7. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you're not going to want to replace the existing python, since that would probably break the existing OS software.

You could either build a package for python 2.7, and have it install as /usr/bin/python2.7, or install in another location like /usr/local/bin/python.  Or, you could just compile manually and install in /usr/local.  If you're installing to an alternate location, use [make altinstall](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/using/unix.html#building-python).

Comment: I recommend a location like `/opt/python-2.7` or `/usr/local/stow/python-2.7`. Don't put manually-installed programs in `/usr` (outside `/usr/local`), it will make the package management a lot less useful for no good reason. I recommend a separate location, not directly `/usr/local/bin/python`, so you can decide to switch to your python by adding e.g. `/opt/python-2.7/bin` to the front of your `PATH`.

Comment: @Gilles: I agree.  I'd only put files in /usr/bin if I were packaging them, and some people prefer to package things into /usr/local/bin (although it's not something I'd suggest).

Comment: where can i a get the binary package?

Comment: zr01:  The instructions I gave was for building it from source.  I'm not aware of any third party repos that provide python 2.7 packages that are safe for OpenSUSE 11.